# Move semantics and operator + overloading

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I'm given a simple CTab class which contains such fields as 1 dimensional array's pointer, array's size and following copy constructor:

```
CTab::CTab(const CTab &cOther)
{
    pi_tab = new int[cOther.i_size];
    i_size = cOther.i_size;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < cOther.i_size; ii++)
        pi_tab[ii] = cOther.pi_tab[ii];
    std::cout << "Copy ";
}
```

On the move semantics needs, I also wrote move construcor:

```
CTab::CTab(CTab && cOther)
{
    pi_tab = cOther.pi_tab;
    i_size = cOther.i_size;
    cOther.pi_tab = NULL;
    cOther.i_size = 0;
    std::cout << "MOVE ";
}
```

Previously, I was asked to overload '+' operator so it returns concatenation of 2 arrays. Now, I'm struggling with modification that uses move semantics in order to decrease number of made copies. I have no idea which part of previous code would produce unnecessary copies and if so, how to change the code so it meets the condition of the given task. Any ideas?

Overloaded operator without usage of move semantics:

```
CTab CTab::operator+(const CTab cOther)
{
    CTab newTab;
    newTab.bSetSize(i_size + cOther.i_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < i_size; i++)
        newTab.pi_tab[i] = pi_tab[i];
    for (int i = i_size; i < i_size+cOther.i_size; i++)
        newTab.pi_tab[i] = cOther.pi_tab[i - i_size];
    return newTab;
}
```

Comment: "*int i = i_size; i < i_size*" So... you want to loop zero times?

Comment: FWIW, if you make `pi_tab` a `std::vector<int>` you can get rid of `i_size` and then you don't need to write any of the copy or move constructors/assignment operators since `std::vector` "does the right thing".

Comment: @NicolBolas Yep, should have been i_size+cOther.s_size, goofy mistake

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure if I'm allowed to modify current structure of CTab.

Comment: Consider making the overload a non-member function. See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators.

Comment: no need to call move constructor on calling your operator `+`. you should do as the answer suggests. It works on returning the value as `CTab newCTabObj{tabObj1+tabObj2}`

Comment: You might want to check against allocating an array with 0 length (both in the copy constructor and `operator+`). These are not a problem but it is inefficient to do.

Comment: Instead of *describing* the members, create a [mcve] to *show* us the definition.  Make sure it's *minimal* - only include enough to demonstrate the problem, but it must be *complete* - easy to check by compiling it.

Comment: btw concatenating arrays via `operator+` is often used as a suboptimal example of operator overloading, because `+` is expected to be commutative (ie `a + b == b + a`), but concatenating arrays is not. Just saying, of course  in a context where it is clear what the operator means you can use it to do whatever

Answer (score 5):

Your `CTab` type can gain nothing from being able to move from its arguments to `operator+`. The output of any `+` operation will have to create a new `CTab` that is the sum of the sizes of its arguments. That means allocating new memory for this new object rather than being able to borrow the storage from one of the arguments.

So you should just take a `const &` to the parameter and move on.

Comment: I suppose that OP wants to know what the move semantic as to do with the return value of the operator...

Comment: wouldn't `return std::move(newTab)` be a good idea? Of course you would need to change the return value in the prototype, too...

Comment: No, there are (almost) no reasons to ever move the return value. There will happen no copy due to return value optimization.